# Остается соединения по socket C

Tags: linux, c, сокет

[Код программы](https://gist.github.com/nikonok/90639c2f02a5b06c8b4364e159758b8d)

Разрабатываю демон под Linux для передачи по TCP порту файлов по протоколу HTTP/POST. (Стоит 8082 порт, для отладки программы)
Столкнулся с проблемой, что после отправки черезе curl файла и закрытия сокета, как будто-то устанвливается новое соединения и выдает ошибку.
Использую блокирующий сокет.

```
curl -F "md5=ab5f2dc27085b9ceb01337fdcf18fb0b" -F "filename=CV.pdf" -F "image=@/home/anton/CV.pdf" http://localhost:8082
```

Код функции прослушки сокета:

```
void listenTCP(int argc, char **argv) {
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
int bytes_read;
char *string_buff[SIZEBUFF];
struct FileTCP fileTCP;

int listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (listener < 0) {
    perror("Socket Error!\n");
    exit(1);
}

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(PORTID); //tcp port linux
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);//INADDR_ANY

if (bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    perror("Bind Error!\n");
    exit(2);
}

listen(listener, 8);//очередь запросов

/* Бесконечный цикл для непрерывной работы программы. Остановка вместе с системой или при сбое. */
while(1) {
    sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Accept Error!\n");
        exit(3);
    }
    FILE *post_file;

    int switcher = -1;
    char *pointer = NULL;
    bytes_read = (int) recv(sock, string_buff, SIZEBUFF, 0);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
        perror("recv Error\n");
        exit(4);
    }
    while (1) {

        if ((bytes_read = (int) recv(sock, string_buff, SIZEBUFF, 0)) <= 0)
            break;
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            pointer = pharsePost(&fileTCP, (char *) string_buff, &switcher, &bytes_read);
            post_file = fopen((char *) fileTCP.filename, "wb");
            if (pointer != NULL) {
                fwrite(pointer, sizeof(char), bytes_read - 6, post_file);
            }
        } else {
            fwrite(string_buff, sizeof(char), bytes_read, post_file);
        }
        bzero(string_buff, SIZEBUFF);
    }

    shutdown(sock, 2);
    close(sock);
    close(listener);
    fclose(post_file);

    if (formatPostFile((char *) fileTCP.filename) == 0) {
        perror("truncate Error!\n");
        exit(5);
    }

    if (fileMD5((char *) fileTCP.filename, (char *) fileTCP.md5) != 0) {
        remove((char *) fileTCP.filename);
        printf("Hash failed!\n");
    }else{
        printf("File received!\n");
    }
}
```

}

Прошу простить за безграмотность, так как первый раз пишу что-то подобное.
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Подробно я Ваши исходы не анализировал, но явных ляпов не заметил. Вопросы:

**как будто-то устанвливается новое соединения** - откуда это следует?


**выдает ошибку** - кто выдаёт? Каков текст сообщения об ошибке ?

Comment: @Sergey, после успешной передачи файла, цикл идет на новую итерацию, а на ней возникает ошибка (дескриптор сокета равен -1) из-за этого не возможно продолжить работу программы Есть еще вопрос, curl ожидает ответ? Потому что сам не завершается, только если через ошибку или принудительно

Конкретный участок с ошибкой
`sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Accept Error!\n");
        exit(3);
    }`

Comment: **на ней возникает ошибка (дескриптор сокета равен -1)** - ну а что же выдаёт *perror("Accept Error!\n");*,

Comment: По идее, если сокет блокирующий, а нового запроса на соединение нет - то просто повисаем на *accept*. Ошибка может возникнуть только если сокет НЕблокирующий.

Comment: Погодите, а где Вы закрываете соединение ? В мане вот что пишут по этому поводу: *When no longer required, the socket  should be deleted using unlink(2) or remove(3) *  Есть у Вас это?

Comment: @Sergey, Все разобрался
Я закрывал серверный сокет(`listener`), просто невнимательность. Спасибо за помощь!
Но остается вопрос: мне же необходимо отправить response? Потому что curl все еще сам не завершается

Comment: **мне же необходимо отправить response?** - поскольку *curl* в данном конкретном примере использует проткол HTTP,  то, скорее всего, она ждёт от сервера нечто вроде "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

Comment: @Sergey, может сможете на такой вопрос ответить
Я исползую блокирующие сокеты и curl после отправки post почему-то не отправляет ничего, поэтому read ничего не возвращает, а просто блокирует программу
Есть ли способ это обойти?

Comment: **curl после отправки post почему-то не отправляет ничего**  А почему она должна что-то отправлять?! По протоколу HTTP, после отправки POST клиент должен ЖДАТЬ ОТВЕТА от сервера.  Приблизительный формат этого ответа я дал в предыдущем комментарии.